NextJS: Error: Cannot find module from [dot]next folder even though the file exists
I have a simple next application where /admin route lists the records and /new route open the form and after submitting the records it again redirects to the /admin page.

When I land on the /admin route the /api/list api triggers.
When lands to the /new route the /api/insert api triggers.

Now the problem is,
-> when I land to the /admin page at that time /api/list api triggers and get the records. But after that when go to the /new page to insert the records at that time after filling the form and click the submit button the api/insert throws an error saying that error - Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/.next/server/pages/api/insertRecords.js'
-> AND if I directly go to the /new page and submit the records the api /api/insert works fine but at that time to redirect the page again on the /admin the api/list api not works to lists the records and throws the error as error - Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/.next/server/pages/api/fetchRecords.js'

next.config.js file
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig

I have tried these [1] , [2] solutions but none of them work for me.
